# How to resolve 'Don't know how to pluck from a closure' error in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

The code below works if I remove the Sys.sleep() from within the map() function.  I tried to research the error ('Don't know how to pluck from a closure') but i haven't found much on that topic.

Does anyone know where I can find documentation on this error, and any help on why it is happening and how to prevent it?

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

# lets assume 3 pages only to do it quickly
page <- (0:18)

# no need to create a list. Just a vector
urls = paste0("https://www.mlssoccer.com/players?page=", page)

# define this function that collects the player's name from a url
get_the_names = function( url){
  url %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes("a.name_link") %>% 
    html_text()
}

# map the urls to the function that gets the names
players = map(urls, get_the_names) %>% 
# turn into a single character vector
unlist() %>% 
# make lower case
tolower() %>% 
# replace the `space` to underscore
str_replace_all(" ", "-")


# Now create a vector of player urls
player_urls = paste0("https://www.mlssoccer.com/players/", players )


# define a function that reads the 3rd table of the url
get_the_summary_stats <-  function(url){

  url %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes("table") %>% 
    html_table() %>% .[[3]]

}

# lets read 3 players only to speed things up [otherwise it takes a significant amount of time to run...]
a_few_players <- player_urls[1:5]

# get the stats 
tables = a_few_players %>% 
# important step so I can name the rows I get in the table
set_names() %>% 
#map the player urls to the function that reads the 3rd table
# note the `safely` wrap around the get_the_summary_stats' function
# since there are players with no stats and causes an error (eg.brenden-aaronson )
# the output will be a list of lists [result and error]
map(., ~{ Sys.sleep(5) 
  safely(get_the_summary_stats) }) %>%
# collect only the `result` output (the table) INTO A DATA FRAME
# There is also an `error` output
# also, name each row with the players name
map_df("result", .id = "player") %>% 
#keep only the player name (remove the www.mls.... part)
mutate(player = str_replace(player, "https://www.mlssoccer.com/players/", "")) %>%
as_tibble()

tables <- tables %>% separate(Match,c("awayTeam","homeTeam"), extra= "drop", fill = "right")
```

Comment: `purrr::safely(...)` returns a function, so your `map(., { Sys.sleep(5); safely(get_the_summary_stats) })` is returning functions, not any data. In R, a "closure" is a function and its enclosing environment. Perhaps you mean something like `map(., ~safely(get_the_summary_stats)(.))`?

Comment: What does the (.) at the end do?

Comment: Tilde notation is a `tidyverse`-specific method of more-terse anonymous functions. Typically (e.g., with `lapply`) one would use `lapply(mydata, function(x) get_the_summary_stats(x))`. In tilde notation, the same thing is written as `map(mydata, ~ get_the_summary_stats(.))`.

Comment: (I should note that this "tilde notation" is unique to `tidyverse`, not necessarily available in other functions. I believe it's actually being done in `rlang`, a package used in many of the `tidyverse` packages, but I'm not certain exactly *where*.)

Comment: Thanks.  Where is the right place to insert the Sys.sleep()?

Comment: Perhaps `... %>% map(~ { Sys.sleep(5); safely(get_the_summary_stats)(.); })`

Comment: Thanks @r2evans - that does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

`purrr::safely(...)` returns a function, so your `map(., { Sys.sleep(5); safely(get_the_summary_stats) })` is returning functions, not any data. In R, a "closure" is a function and its enclosing environment.

Tilde notation is a tidyverse-specific method of more-terse anonymous functions. Typically (e.g., with `lapply)` one would use `lapply(mydata, function(x) get_the_summary_stats(x))`. In tilde notation, the same thing is written as `map(mydata, ~ get_the_summary_stats(.))`

So, re-write to:

```
... %>% map(~ { Sys.sleep(5); safely(get_the_summary_stats)(.); })
```

From comments by [@r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans)